# how to create customer map on iPhone without using Google Map

Tags: iphone, dictionary

I'm trying to integrated in our iOS app. Due to the bad relationship between Google & our government, Google Map is not a good idea.

We have bought a local map service company's javascript & Web Services based SDK, now we want to use it on iOS. But it seems that MapKit does not support customer tiles.

So here are my current ideas:

- Use UIWebView. But I tried that map in Safari, I can't drag to move the map nor use two fingers to zoom. I think I need to call some javascripts while touch events happens.
- Build a costumer UIScrollView, download map images and display them using iOS sdk. But that map service does not have API to download images, I tried to read their 200KB+ undocumented javascript to find out the relationship between location & image files, but I got no results for now.

Both the two ways could face certain legal risks. I'm not sure what the purchase contract is like.

I need suggestions about the two ways or some new ideas. Thanks guys.

Comment: "I'm not sure what the purchase contract is like." Why don't you ask?

Comment: @Raoul, I haven't saw my boss today, I'll ask tomorrow. I'll update as soon as I got any info about the contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of non-Google map implementations available on github that you might be able to use (linked via [CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com)):

- [NAMapKit](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/namapkit)
- [MRMapView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mrmapview)

Comment: & @Jano, after a quick look of the three lib's src, NAMapKit seems to display map from one UIImage, that doesn't seem to match what I need. The others use tiles so I could use one of them if I worked out the huge javascript file. I'll try them ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: maybe you should also check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534691/how-to-geolocalize-on-custom-maps-iphone-and-android/6534929#6534929