# How to geolocalize on custom maps iphone and android

Tags: iphone, android, dictionary, geolocation

My client would like me to implement geolocation in a mobile application. He want me to use a map which is quite deformed (definitely not a google-like map). Is it an easy way to transform the GPS coordinates into the coordinates on that deformed map?

I get the coordinates (X0,Y0) from the GPS -> I need the location on my client's map (X1,Y1)

Comment: can you please guide me how you get the X Y from GPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, you should try [http://trimaps.com](http://trimaps.com/en/). It does exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the mapping from the client map to real world co-ordinates. Either ask your client, or perhaps you could overlay it on a google map of the same area in photoshop and work out how much you need to stretch it by in each dimension, this might get you close enough if the distortion is linear.

Comment: Thank for the answer but I am afraid the mapping will not be as accurate as my client want it to be. It must be some kind of library/tool to do that work...