# math converting coordinates to pixels in PHP

Tags: php, dictionary, chord

This is the script I have so far...

I am trying to get SEA SURFACE TEMP DATA, I am close but I seem to be missing something...

the center of the map is 1578px Horz and 839px Vert, for every degree in lng or lat its 4.6666px.

so 0.0lat 0.0lng will be 1578px 839px on the map. 1.0lat 1.0lng will be 1573px 834px on the map.

```
$Lat = round($_GET['lat']*4.66666)+1578;
$Lng = round($_GET['lng']*4.66666)+839;

address of the IMG : ospo.noaa.gov/data/sst/contour/global_small.cf.gif
```

thanks so much for taking a look!

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020771/convert-lat-long-to-pixel-xy-co-ordinates?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I think to get any useful feedback you will need to give an example of the desired result and the error that you are getting.  Your code simply shows some math but no where near enough code and info to identify the error let alone reproduce it - suggest you update, expand and amend your question before it is downvoted.  Even the question title is not explanatory or helpful in a search since you cannot convert co-ordinates to pixels, however you can calculate the position of a pixel.

Comment: Your question is very vague and imprecise, but if it helps in any way at all I developed a simple mapping location system.  I calculated the position as x and y co-ordinates  and stored them in a database.  When the database was queried the x and y co-ordinates were used to position a div over the map image at the desired location.  But I am not sure if your question is related to creating the pixels, positioning them or calculating them.

Comment: I can't see a question or a problem. It looks to me like the calculation should work.

Comment: Finally did get it working using

$Lat = round($Lat*(139/20))+1575 ;
$Lng = round($Lng*(134/20))+839;