# iphone geolocation over custom image?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit

i want to develop a application similar to "mall guides" that track the position of the user and is able to show how to navigate around the mall (image to get a better idea - http://navigationapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/point-inside-2.png). I'm new to iPhone development but i believe it's just a geolocation on top of a custom map?. So my question is, because i have tried to look for tutorials/guides - how can i load a image and place a geolocation pin on top of it? (also is my attempt to do this right? if not, what is the proper way to approach this?). Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534691/

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

The big part of your job will be to match GPS coordinates with the custom image/maps you are trying to display. There should be some sort of correlation between the two spatial coordinate systems.

Once that's out of the way, you are simply displaying an UIImageView and starting CoreLocation services to get the current GPS coordinates, then plot it on top of your image.

Here's a good reference for the conversion between GPS and pixel coordinates:

[Help calculating X and Y from Latitude and Longitude in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852195/help-calculating-x-and-y-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-iphone)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Could you please elaborate on the second part of your answer (displaying the geolocation services on a custom image). How would this work exactly? - how can i set the mkmap source to a uiimageview? (would appreciate it if you know any working examples)

Comment: You wouldn't touch MKMap in this case. Use CoreLocation services to get the current users coordinates and then you just need to pass that your method that translates it into X,Y coordinates. Once you have the corresponding X,Y coordinates you can simply put an image to represent the users location anywhere on the screen. Here's the documentation you need to get started http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: you will still need map kit to have the blue "showUserLocation" mark appearing.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. So at present i am able to obtain the longitude and latitude of the user using core data. What do i do next? Am i supposed to convert these into X and Y points and place the 'pointer' (which denotes the players current location - which i assume will be another image) onto the map. Then as the log and lat changes, it gets converted into x and y points which in turn updates the position on the map. Or am i wrong and over complicating things? Or how else can i place the pointer onto the image?

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do.