# how can i co-relate lat/longs of myHome  to the pixels of myHome image in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, latitude-longitude, pixel

I have top view image of my house and know lat longitude for left top pixel i.e 0,0 and lat/longs of all four corners of my home. now how to get latitude longitude values of other pixels?

Comment: You'll need to create a mapping between lat/lon and x-y space.  I explain how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `MKMapView` already defines a method to do just this for you: [`convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW8). You pass in a `CGPoint` and the `UIView` whose coordinate system the point is in reference to, and the method gives you a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, which includes lat and long.