# ios how to create simple map app from image

Tags: ios

I'm new here, so please be gentle :)

General idea:
I'm building a (simple) location-based app for hikers,
and i would like to create a map from a custom image (2D image.jpg 
of some mountain) that i have.
My purpose is to show the hiker (the user) his current location
on that image (not necessarily guide him/navigate).

Data i have:
 - 4 Lat/Long coordinates of the rectangular area (4 "corners" of the mountain).
 - Image of the mountain (NOT a real picture, a drawing of it!!!).

For now, my app can:
 - locate the user - with CoreLocation to obtain the Lat/Long.
 - display the image - with UIImageView.

What's left:
 - show the user's current location on the image.

I have already read the: [Help calculating X and Y from Latitude and Longitude in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852195/help-calculating-x-and-y-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-iphone)
and more...still i'm a bit confused.

My question is:
Am i thinking straight?

How can i set the IMAGE boundaries to hold the 4 Lat/Long coordinates
and translate / scale the coordinates to points on the image map?

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the map view itself in satellite mode?

Comment: I wish :)
but my client wants a custom image instead.

Comment: Please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection Now the math model completely depends on the image projection method and desired accuracy.

Comment: Thanks, read it. to much theory for me :(
I just need help with converting (Lon, Lat) to (X, Y) on the iPhone screen. I Read some more SO answers about this topic and it seems there are others in my situation.