# Relative coordinate calculation in custom map

Tags: iphone, geolocation, maps, trigonometry

I'm currently working on a mapping app for iPhone. I've created some custom maps of various sizes, but I've run into an issue:

I would like to implement the ability for users' locations to be checked automatically, but since Im not using a MapView this is much more dificult. (see below)

[image: map]

given the different coordinate systems, I would like to receive a geolocation (green dot) and translate it into a pixel location on a custom map. 
Ive got the geolocations for the 4 corners, but the rect is askew. Ive calculated the angle of rotation, but Im just generally confused.

note: the size of the maps arent big enough for the spherical nature of the earth to come into calculation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534691/

Comment: Did you find out any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

To convert a geolocation to point you need to first understand the mapping. assuming you are using Mercator.

```
x = R*long
y = R*(1+sin(lat))/cos(lat)
```

where lat and long are in radians.R is radius of earth. the scale of the image would be from `0 to R*PI`

so to get it within view.frame.size you may have to divide by a scale factor.

for difference between points.

```
x2-x1 = R* (long2-long1)
y2-y1 = R* (  (1+sin(lat2))/cos(lat2) - (1+sin(lat1))/cos(lat1)  )
```