# Custom map for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, dictionary

I'd like to make an app which would use custom map (instead of Google's map), transferred via WMS (Web Map Service). As far as I understand, I can't use MapKit, because there is no way to get rid of Google maps. So, the only way seems to be implementing my own map system. But which would be the best way to do it? I also want the map to have the features like showing user's current location etc. Maybe I should start from the scrollview?

Comment: How about designing a web interface and showing it in UIWebView?

Comment: An interesting idea. But has anybody done it with online maps?

Comment: Well I used this idea a few times, but never to complicated. If you have time, try implementing some base functionality and see if it suits you.

Comment: I'll see how it manages downloading different areas of the map (my map is really big - 400x400 km)

Comment: Trimaps implements the features you are looking for. Check this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534691/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your drawing, start with a [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). That helps you load the different tiles asynchronously, and pan and zoom without slowdown. It's pretty poorly documented, although there are a few examples (like [this one](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example)) scattered around the net. It does work though: it is used to draw a custom map in my company's app [Timeline World War 2](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/timeline-world-war-2-dan-snow/id516540098?mt=8).

For things like showing the user's current location, you'll need some algorithms to translate from latitude/longitude (that you found out through Core Location) into whatever projection your map is currently using, and then get the scroll view containing your tiled layer to move to the right position.